# Not counting weekend days in an interval

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I want to get a timestamp which is X **week days** before another timestamp.

I can only get to a timestamp which is X **days** before another timestamp:

```
select item.timestamp - (X * interval '1' day)
```

How can I upgrade this query to not count weekend days?

Comment: We don't know what schedule your business observes.  Do you have a calendar table someplace and if so what is the structure?  What about days closed due to force majeure?

Comment: @jjanes I've upgraded the question to week days instead of business days. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to substract 7 days for every 5 days, plus subtract the remainder days (after dividing by 5), and subtract another two days if the remainder subtraction will put you back into/through a weekend.  So something like this:

```
create or replace function minus_weekdays(timestamptz, int) returns timestamptz language sql as $$ 
   select $1 - interval '1 day' * case 
      when extract(DOW from $1+interval '1 day') <= ($2%5)+1 
      then 7*($2/5)+($2%5)+2 
      else 7*($2/5)+($2%5) end; 
$$;
```

This will probably do the wrong thing if called on a date which is already a weekend day, but I don't know what you *want* to do that in that case.